# Calc price based on parseInt

Tags: javascript, jquery, parseint

I have two inputs, where user types `width` and `height` of a product (let's say in mm). So min price is $250 until `width=50` and `height=20`. Then I want to increase total price by $25 every time width OR height edited by 10mm. So total should be $275 if `w=60 and h=20` (or `w=50/h=30`); $300 - when `w=60 and h=30`...

Now with my poor jquery knowledge I made this monster https://jsfiddle.net/fkqotzzb/

```js
var basePrice = 250;
var priceForSm = 50;
var price300 = basePrice + priceForSm;
var price450 = price300 + (priceForSm * 3);
var price700 = price450 + (priceForSm * 5);
var price950 = price700 + (priceForSm * 5);

$("#stwidth, #stheight").keyup(function () {

 var stwidth = parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10);
 var stheight = parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10);

 if (stwidth > 113) {
  $("#stwidth").val("113");
 }
  
  if (stheight > 62) {
  $("#stheight").val("62");
 }

 if (stwidth >= 50 && stheight >= 20 || stwidth >= 110 && stheight >= 10) {
  $(".stamp-full-price span").html(basePrice);

 }

 if (stwidth >= 30 && stheight >= 60 || stwidth == 80 && stheight == 20 || stwidth >= 60 && stheight >= 30 || stwidth >= 40 && stheight >= 40) {
  $(".stamp-full-price span").html(price300);
 }

 if (stwidth >= 110 && stheight >= 20 || stwidth >= 110 && stheight == 30 || stwidth >= 70 && stheight >= 30 || stwidth >= 60 && stheight >= 40 || stwidth >= 50 && stheight >= 50 || stwidth >= 40 && stheight >= 60) {
  $(".stamp-full-price span").html(price450);
 }

 if (stwidth >= 110 && stheight >= 40 || stwidth >= 110 && stheight >= 50 || stwidth >= 90 && stheight >= 40 || stwidth >= 80 && stheight >= 50 || stwidth >= 60 && stheight >= 60) {
  $(".stamp-full-price span").html(price700);
 }

 if (stwidth >= 100 && stheight >= 60 || stwidth >= 111 && stheight >= 50) {
  $(".stamp-full-price span").html(price950);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stwidth" id="stwidth" value="50" class="form-control input-xs" maxlength="3"> x <input type="text" name="stheight" id="stheight" value="20" class="form-control input-xs" maxlength="2"> мм

<div class="stamp-full-price">
  Total: <span>250</span>
</div>
```

Here prices and sizes set manually, but I don't want to set them so, it could be nice to control price by `width` and `height` separately.
It also doesn't cover all the sizes an cases, so I can't predict what price could be shown in specific situation, and it's really monster :).

I also have some another options next after sizes in form of radios and checkboxes. So how to get value of a total price after sizes defined to add a price of radio/checkbox?

Comment: paste your code in the question (not just the link to the fiddle)

Comment: the best scenario is figure out some formula that you need to calculate the price based on the dimensions. then add that to a function in the event handler(s)

Comment: @LukasLiesis, I read too quickly :( i am going to bed ! I will delete my Orig comment to clean up thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you already have found way to get width/height and want to increment price by $25 for every extra 10, just make a math:

```
var stwidth = parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10);
var stheight = parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10);

var price = 250;

if(stwidth > 50) {
  price += 25 * Math.ceil((stwidth - 50) / 10)
}

if(stheight > 20) {
  price += 25 * Math.ceil((stheight - 20) / 10)
}

$(".stamp-full-price span").html(price);
```

When you are in similar situation always try to make math how you would count it on paper, maybe it will be easier to learn faster and get it done. You can just write down all steps how you count price for some values and then just replace some parts with variables.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks! And what about adding some another amount of $ to calculated price, when a checkbox selected?

Comment: So just add one more if clause `if(checked){ price += X }` or if you want to increment not by $25 but some other value when checked, then make 25 as variable and change it's value before doing the math

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution, where price calculated on rounded values

```js
var basePrice = 250;
var baseW = 50;
var baseH = 20;

$("#stwidth, #stheight").keyup(function () {
 var stwidth = parseInt($("#stwidth").val(), 10);
 var stheight = parseInt($("#stheight").val(), 10);

 var dW = (stwidth - baseW) > 0 ? Math.round((stwidth - baseW)/10) : 0;
 var dH = (stheight - baseH) > 0 ? Math.round((stheight - baseH)/10) : 0;
        var price = basePrice + dW*25 +dH*25;
        $(".stamp-full-price span").html(price);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="stwidth" id="stwidth" value="50" class="form-control input-xs" maxlength="3"> x 
<input type="text" name="stheight" id="stheight" value="20" class="form-control input-xs" maxlength="2"> мм

<div class="stamp-full-price">
  Total: <span>250</span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is wrong because you use round function which will make round down in some scenarios, check my answer for correct math. With your math price will be same for width = 51 as it would be 50, while it should already have $25 increase

Comment: @LukasLiesis , sure. Math.ceil fits much better then round.  At first edit I didn't use Math at all. It calculated almost right.

Comment: @Banzay in Math there is no such thing as `almost right` it's correct or incorrect, if we would agree to pay you 100$ and i would send you $1.00 it would be also almost right visually, but you wouldn't be happy, are you?

Comment: @LukasLiesis The solution can not be more precise than the task. Author asked to increase price by 25 for every 10 units, but didn't clarify if it should be a either discrete or continuous dependency. Your suggestion won. It's simple.